# Why does WPF render two identical objects differently?

Tags: wpf

Take this Window as an example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid Width="17" Margin="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Polyline RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="1" Fill="Red">
                <Polyline.Points>
                    <Point X="0" Y="3" />
                    <Point X="3" Y="0" />
                    <Point X="6" Y="3" />
                </Polyline.Points>
            </Polyline>
        </RepeatButton>

        <RepeatButton Grid.Row="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Polyline RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="1" Fill="Red">
                <Polyline.Points>
                    <Point X="0" Y="3" />
                    <Point X="3" Y="0" />
                    <Point X="6" Y="3" />
                </Polyline.Points>
            </Polyline>
        </RepeatButton>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Once the application has been ran, the topmost RepeatButton is taller than the bottom one (consequently the top triangle is also bigger than the bottom one). Why?
If I create 4 rows of identical RepeatButtons, then the 1-st and 3-rd RepeatButtons are of equal size and are bigger than the 2-nd and 4-th RepeatButton?!?

I'm thinking this must be a bug in the WPF layout system, but how to work around this problem? I can't use fixed heights (which does solve the problem), because I need the RepeatButtons and triangles to strecth as the container gets bigger (the example I provided is simplifed just to show the issue, I know I can't resize the example window...).

## Edit:

In reply to Ben's comments:

Yes, with the added style the triangles do come out as 9px and 8px tall (I could just as well through out the RepeatButtons alltogether and leave only the polylines as the grids children, that would give the same result). Because the triangles are equal sided, then giving the grid a width of 17 will indeed cause the height to become 17 as well, which of course is not enough for two equal height triangles..

What I'm actually trying to do is create a NumericUpDown control. I've found that by default a spinner width of 17 and a UserControl MinHeight of 24 looks very good. The only problem is, that if I drop this UserControl into a Grid, then the top triangle always pushes itself 1px to tall, ruining the look. No matter how I've tried to mingle with the internal Margins and Paddings, the top triangle always makes itself 1px taller than necessary. So in essence what I want is to have a NumericUpDown, that when put into a Grid, doesn't distort itself. By default it should look perfect from the get go (no Grid RowHeight="Auto") and scale properly (no fixed heights). It must be possible, because by looking at the pixels physically then everything can fit into the given dimensions nicely.

Here is my NumericUpDown, I've stripped out all the non essential things to make it more compact:

```
<UserControl x:Class="HRS.NumericUpDown"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             MinWidth="40" MinHeight="24" Name="ucNUPD" Background="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                        <Border Name="borderOuter" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
                            <Border Name="borderInner" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Blue">
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="2,1"  />
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="triangleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                        <Polyline HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Green" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Uniform">
                            <Polyline.Points>
                                <Point X="0" Y="3" />
                                <Point X="3" Y="0" />
                                <Point X="6" Y="3" />
                            </Polyline.Points>
                        </Polyline>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ABADB3">  
        <DockPanel>
            <UniformGrid Margin="1" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Rows="2" MinWidth="17" Width="17">
                <RepeatButton Name="repeatButtonUp" Grid.Row="0">
                    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource triangleStyle}" />
                </RepeatButton>

                <RepeatButton Name="repeatButtonDown" Grid.Row="1">
                    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource triangleStyle}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                        <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
                        </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                    </ContentControl>
                </RepeatButton>
            </UniformGrid>

            <TextBox BorderThickness="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="0" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Here is a picture of what the end result looks like:
[image: Result]

(The image doesn't fit a 100%, but you can still see all the relevant details).

On the right side you can see a zoom-in of the NumericUpDowns. The bottom one looks correct, but only because the grid's row Height is set to Auto. The top one is distorted, but by default I want it to look exactly like the bottom one.

**Hmmm...**
I might just have found a workable solution:
It seems that by setting the Margin of the ContentPresenter in my NumericUpDown to "3,1", everything looks perfect. Preliminary testing is very promising as everything seems to be exactly the way it should be...
I'll test it some more tommorow and if all goes good will mark Ben's answer as correct :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" the height will be 17 as you you set the Grid's Width to 17. But with 17/2=8.5 one row will be 9 (rounding occurs becouse of SnapsToDevicePixels="True") but the other will be 8 pixel tall. If you set the Width to 18 they will be equal.

Proof of my theory:

```
<Grid Width="17" Margin="0">
<Grid.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
            <ContentPresenter Margin="0"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</Grid.Resources>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition />
  <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<RepeatButton Grid.Row="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
  <Polyline RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0" Fill="Red">
    <Polyline.Points>
      <Point X="0" Y="3" />
      <Point X="3" Y="0" />
      <Point X="6" Y="3" />
    </Polyline.Points>
  </Polyline>
</RepeatButton>

<RepeatButton Grid.Row="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
  <Polyline RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0" Fill="Red">
    <Polyline.Points>
      <Point X="0" Y="3" />
      <Point X="3" Y="0" />
      <Point X="6" Y="3" />
    </Polyline.Points>
  </Polyline>
</RepeatButton>
```

With this snippet you gain a Triangle that has 9 pixel height, and one with 8 pixels.

But if you want for a solution try this:

```
<RepeatButton Grid.Row="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}" >
  <Polyline RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0" Fill="Red">
    <Polyline.Points>
      <Point X="0" Y="3" />
      <Point X="3" Y="0" />
      <Point X="6" Y="3" />
    </Polyline.Points>
  </Polyline>
</RepeatButton>
```

This way the width and the height of the buttons will be equal.

If think you can write a little converter too, that will can do some nasty things:

```
<RepeatButton Grid.Row="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource TriangleWidthConverter}}" >
  <Polyline RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0" Fill="Red">
    <Polyline.Points>
      <Point X="0" Y="3" />
      <Point X="3" Y="0" />
      <Point X="6" Y="3" />
    </Polyline.Points>
  </Polyline>
</RepeatButton>  

public class TriangleWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    int width = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out width))
      return width + 1; // Do some fun here.
    return value;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

I hope these will help.

Comment: I agree with Ben although I would add to it that the other reason this happens is because you have SnapsToDevicePixels="True". By setting this you are telling WPF that you want everything to have an edge on an actual pixel boundary. Since you have an even number of items but odd pixels WPF has to make one a different size then the other.

Comment: @Matt West You are true, but i left it out becouse i tought that Marko knows what the SnapsToDevicePixels do, becouse he set it on almost everything. :)

Comment: You are right that by setting the width to 18, both triangles are of equal size. But what I won't agree upon, is that because the Width is 17 the Height will also be 17. Actually, the first RepeatButton comes out at 13px tall and the second one is 12px. What is strange, is that if I simply remove Stretch="Uniform" from both polylines, then they will both be 12px tall. I've set SnapToDevicePixels purely for the reason to try and eliminate this half pixel rounding problem. If I remove the property from all elements, then the bottom button becomes larger...

Comment: It would seem that the polyline stretching algorithm ignores SnapToDevicePixels thus causing this problem. I also need both RepeatButtons width to be of an odd number, because I want the triangle to be evenly spaced within. Since the triangle's width is always of a non even number, the RepeatButtons width must also be non even...

Comment: The 'RepeatButton' is based on the 'BaseButtonStyle' and have a BroderThickness set to 3, and Padding set to "0,0,1,1", if you want to controll the RepeatButton with these precise numbers you mentioned i think you should restyle the RepeatButton from scratch.

Comment: Creating a new ControlTemplate from scratch for the RepeatButton has no effect. Even if I replace the RepeatButton altogether with a simple border and place the polyline inside the border, then the top triangle is still larger than the bottom one...

Comment: I should perhaps also mention that setting the Grid's RowHeight to Auto does solve the problem of triangles being of unequal size, but it introduces another porblem. The triangles are no longer evenly spaced, I would have to use Margin="0,0,-1,0" on the polyline to get it back into center... This double trickery is not a very good solution, because when scaling bigger the negative right margin starts causing problems...

Comment: @Marko so as you can see in my edited answer when i added the 'Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}"' part to the two RepeatButton i gained two identical triangles.

Comment: Well I copy-pasted your code and still the RepeatButtons height do not match the width. Nor can I see a reason why they should, because SizeToContent=WidthAndHeight allows width and height to be "scaled down" seperately, you don't necessarily end up with a square. After pasting your code, the triangles themselves are 6px and 5px tall. The RepeatButtons are 12px and 11px tall. In no way is anything (including grid rows) 9 and 8 pixels tall... Your suggestion of binding Height to ActualWidth is of no use to me, because I don't want the RepeatButton to be a constant square.

Comment: @Marko I think its time to edit your original question, becouse the original was that the two repeat button is not equal. And i answered that question pretty well i think. Can you write down _clearly_ what you want to achive?

Comment: @Marko Edited my answer becouse the `Style` was hidden becouse it was formatted badly.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you are seeing this behavior, but this might work to fix it: try setting the height on each of your your rows to .5* if you have 2 rows or .25* if you have 4 rows (or .1* if you have 10 rows, etc.).

Comment: Setting the row height to .5* for two rows has no effect.